# Facebook App Center - Need Listed Apps' ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I can get the details of the app using app id and Graph API.

e.g https://graph.facebook.com/**2439131959**/insights/application_active_users?since=1329724800&until=1329984000

However, is there any way to get the list of apps and their id so that I can use above query with access-token to get the app info?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook User Object has the connection object called "accounts".  Using this can get the facebook apps and pages owned by the current user. In order get these details via graph api, you need "manage_pages" permissions.  This will return array of objects containing account name, access_token, category and id.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts
```

[checkout fb documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Comment: but prob it,I don't have any permissions or tokens. I just want to gather this data for research purpose. I don't own any page or anything like that.

Comment: but you can get a permissions from your app users and if they have pages or apps then you can get the data.  The apps and user details are private info which you can't access it without having proper permissions. :(

Comment: The thing is I don't own any app. :( I just need data of some apps for research purpose.